# how to calculate clicked element in a grid

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, arraylist, grid

I have a grid:

[image: grid]

It's a 3x16 grid total of 48 elements.

**Width:** 1100

**Height:** 200

It means each element has width of 69 and height 67.

How can I calculate the clicked element in the grid? (The grid's element is implemented by an ArrayList).

Basically i want to get the index of the clicked element in the arrayList
(just need the algorithm but im using java)

Comment: If I understand you right you can simply check if (clickpoint.x between i*69 and (i+1)*69) and if (clickpoint.y between j*67 and (j+1)*67)

Comment: tell me one thing,  when someone clicks on the grid, do we get to know the at what width and height the person has clicked ?

Comment: of course you get x and y of the clicked position (MouseEvent object)

Comment: you could divide your input's x coordinate with 69 and y coordinate with 67, that should give you the selected block of the grid in terms of row and column value of the selected block, This should help you move forward with your problem.